# Query with self-joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, self-join

I have purchases, which may (or may not) have an associated sub-purchase, which i've modelled with a self-join as:

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :sub_purchase, class_name: 'Purchase', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :main_purchase, class_name: 'Purchase', foreign_key: 'purchase_id', optional: true
end
```

Purchases have an attribute, status, which may be 'active'. How do I query for sub-purchases, with a main purchase that is active?

Something close to this perhaps?:

```
Purchase.where.not(purchase_id:nil).where(main_purchase: {status: 'active'})
```

UPDATE:
In SQL, I have discovered I can alias the purchases table twice and do something like this:

```
SELECT
FROM
purchases p1 INNER JOIN purchases p2 ON p2.id = p1.purchase_id
WHERE p2.status='active';
```

but it would be nice to not use SQL directly if it's possible to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually trying it:

```
Purchase.joins(:main_purchase).where(main_purchase: {status: 'active'})
```